# How to stop npm run my-script from outputting "script info", before the actual script output

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run the following:

```
$ npm run test
```

There is some *info on the run script*:

```
> my-module@1.0.0 test /Users/me/my-module
> echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1
```

Followed by the actual output:

```
Error: no test specified
```

Is there a way to stop npm from outputting the *info on the run script*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `-s` option to make npm silent (tested with npm v3.10.8): `npm run test -s`.

Comment: /slaps forehead - Of course. I read the docs, but stupidly I thought that would kill the output of the script itself